# Struggling with lnk2019

Tags: c++

I am attempting to compile an early version of a loan calculator for a project. However, I am getting an error I cannot understand. LNK2019 and LNK1120.

I am new at c++ and coding in general so hopefully this doesn't come across as a dumb question. I am coming from a intro to programming class in c not c++. I appreciate any help I can receive. I am using virtual studio 2022 community edition.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;



void welcome();
double getPrincipal();
double getTerm();
double getAnnualRate();
double convertRate();
double CalcPayment();
void DisplayResults(double, double, double, double);

int main()
{
    double loanPrincipal(0);
    double termLength(0);
    double annualIntRate(0);
    double monthlyIntRate(0);
    double MonPayment(0);

    welcome();
    loanPrincipal = getPrincipal();
    termLength = getTerm();
    annualIntRate = getAnnualRate();
    monthlyIntRate = convertRate();
    MonPayment = CalcPayment();
    DisplayResults(loanPrincipal, termLength, annualIntRate, MonPayment);

    return 0;
}



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

//welcomes the user

void welcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the ammortization loan calculator" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
}

//asks the user for amount of loan

double getPrincipal()
{
    double userPrinicpal = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the loan ammount that you wish to borrow: " << endl;
    double userPrincipal;
    cin >> userPrincipal;

    return userPrincipal;
}

//asks the user for the annual interest rate

double getAnnualRate(double annualIntRate)
{
    cout << "Please enter the annual interest rate: " << endl;
    cin >> annualIntRate;

    return annualIntRate;
}

double convertRate(const double annualIntRate)
{
    double MonIntRate;
    MonIntRate = (annualIntRate / 100) / 12;

    return MonIntRate;
}

//asks the user for the length of the loan

void getTerm(int& termLength)
{
    cout << "Please enter the length of the loan (10, 15, or 30 years)" << endl;
    cin >> termLength;
}

//calculate monthly payment
double CalcPayment(double loanPrincipal, double monthlyIntRate, int termLength)
{
    double MonPayment = loanPrincipal * (monthlyIntRate * (1 + monthlyIntRate) * 180) / ((1 + 0.00375) * 180 - 1);

    return MonPayment;
}

//display results from previous calculations to the user
void DisplayResults(double loanPrincipal, double termLength, double annualIntRate, double MonPayment)
{
    cout << "Loan Application - Amortization Schedule" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Principal:                      " << loanPrincipal << endl;
    cout << "Life of Loan:                   " << termLength << endl;
    cout << "Annual interest rate:           " << annualIntRate << endl;
    cout << "Monthly Payment:                " << MonPayment << endl;
}
```

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl getTerm(void)" (?getTerm@@YANXZ) referenced in function main

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl getAnnualRate(void)" (?getAnnualRate@@YANXZ) referenced in function main

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl convertRate(void)" (?convertRate@@YANXZ) referenced in function

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl CalcPayment(void)" (?CalcPayment@@YANXZ) referenced in function

Error   LNK1120 4 unresolved externals
```

Comment: `double getTerm();` is a forward declaration of a function that has no arguments and returns a `double`. There's no definition of that function in this code. `void getTerm(int& termLength)` is a different function that accepts an `int` by reference and returns nothing. You need to decide which one is the right one and make the other one, and all calls to that function, match. Same with the rest.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I see, working on that now. Thank you.